Looking for fastest packshot-workflow with color accuracy
Hello dear fellow graphic designers.
I am struggling a bit with decision making for the best workflow as I don't have much experience in packshots of variable packaging designs. The part I struggle with mostly is being able to do the color-changes quickly. As I use effects in Photoshop (sRGB file), it tends to switch colors as soon as I change the color space to CMYK.
What I need as an end result:

front-of-pack-packshot with color versions in correct CD colors (cmyk & rgb)

What I don't need:

exact cutter guide dimension accuracy
extra complicated workarounds ;)

At that point I have two workflows in mind, but looking for the one where I'm efficient and able to make corrections fast.

I'd be working with the print-PDF, which means 100% design accuracy but annoying for color corrections as there would be a workaround with making two PDFs (one RGB and one CMYK) and more than one cutter guide, which results in more than one masterfile to work on as I'm taking the PDF as a base.
I'm reconstructing the front-of-pack with one cutter guide dimension as a packshot master and place all the elements where they belong to in Photoshop. This means, once I reconstructed the design in Photoshop, I'm fast with color and text adjustions but don't have 100% design accuracy as sometimes it's a bit of a tinkering around.

Does anyone have good knowledge about packshots or can think of a solution?
I hope it's more or less comprehensible. Thank you in advance!

This seems easy enough, but I'm not sure. I have next to no packaging experience.
But...

View > Proof Setup > Working CMYK (Or whatever is appropriate)

then...

View > Proof Colors

... work in RGB, view as CMYK. This way you don't limit any editing, but actually see colors as they will appear when converted to CMYK.

When you place your elements into Photoshop, try converting them to Smart Objects so you can edit the original elements without destruction and update them across different versions easily.
Also use adjustment layers (such as Hue/Saturation or Color Balance) for color changes. You can toggle the adjustments on and off depending on whether you need the design in RGB or CMYK. I would also love to hear other suggestions and thoughts!
